# How to break if-else-if using C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

How do I break if-else-if.....Why its not working? its just checking all the conditions instead of performing the tasks. following is my code. I have checked it through breakpoints its moving to all conditions why it doesn't get stop after meeting the correct condition. even it is not going into the if activity it just read all the conditions and do nothing at the end.

```
private void ShowHash()
    {
        inpic = pb_selected.Image;
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(inpic);
        byte[] imgBytes = new byte[0];
        imgBytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(image, imgBytes.GetType());
        string hash = ComputeHashCode(imgBytes);
        txt_selectedText.Text = hash;
        GetHash();
    }

private void GetHash()
    {
        if (txt_sel1.Text == null && (txt_sel2.Text == null || txt_sel3.Text == null || txt_sel4.Text == null || txt_sel5.Text == null ))
        {
            txt_sel1.Text = txt_selectedText.Text;
            return;
        }

        else if (txt_sel1.Text != null && (txt_sel2.Text == null || txt_sel3.Text == null || txt_sel4.Text == null || txt_sel5.Text == null))
        {
            txt_sel2.Text = txt_selectedText.Text;
            return;
        }

        else if (txt_sel2.Text != null && (txt_sel3.Text == null || txt_sel4.Text == null || txt_sel5.Text == null))
        {
            txt_sel3.Text = txt_selectedText.Text;
            return;
        }

        else if (txt_sel3.Text != null && (txt_sel4.Text == null || txt_sel5.Text == null))
        {
            txt_sel4.Text = txt_selectedText.Text;
            return;
        }

        else if (txt_sel4.Text != null && (txt_sel5.Text == null))
        {
            txt_sel5.Text = txt_selectedText.Text;
            return;
        }


    }
```

Comment: It's doing that because none of the conditions compute to true.

Comment: press F11 and step through your code, what you think the code does is wrong,the code does what it does, you have to understand what is wrong with your understanding of what  the code is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:**

If there is nothing in those textboxes, `textbox.Text` will return an empty string (`""`) not `null`.

**Solution:**

Check against `""` not `null`:

```
private void GetHash()
{
    if (txt_sel1.Text == "" && (txt_sel2.Text == "" || txt_sel3.Text == "" || txt_sel4.Text == "" || txt_sel5.Text == ""))
    {
        txt_sel1.Text = txt_selectedText.Text;
        return;
    }

    else if (txt_sel1.Text != "" && (txt_sel2.Text == "" || txt_sel3.Text == "" || txt_sel4.Text == "" || txt_sel5.Text == ""))
    {
        txt_sel2.Text = txt_selectedText.Text;
        return;
    }
    ....
    ....
```

**EDIT:** You don't have to do `==true` for boolean variables. If statement checks it against true by default. Use `!` to check against `false`:

```
if (hasValue1 && (hasValue2 || hasValue3 || hasValue4 || hasValue5))
    {
        txt_sel1.Text = txt_selectedText.Text;
        return;
    }

    else if (hasValue2 && (!hasValue1 ||hasValue3 || hasValue4 || hasValue5))
    {                
            txt_sel2.Text = txt_selectedText.Text;
            return;
    }

    else if (hasValue3 && (!hasValue1 || hasValue2 || hasValue4 || hasValue5))
    {               
            txt_sel3.Text = txt_selectedText.Text;
            return;                
    }
    ....
    ....
```

Comment: It worked! but after performing 2nd condition it is not going for 3rd. when it checks  txt_sel1.Text != "" it overwrites the value of txt_sel2.Text not checking the other conditions

Comment: @Sumi: Make sure you haven't used `txt_sel2.Text =` instead of `==` in conditions. Also, if don't have any further code, you can remove `return`. Since you are using `else if`, it will not go for later conditions if anyone of them has met.

Comment: Better use  string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace().

Comment: used you suggestion but still the same problem arrises overwritting the value of txt_sel2.Text . and = is not acceptable for boolean.

Comment: @Sumi: I can't find any problem here, try using breakpoint or watch to identify where the value is being changed.

Comment: @Sumi: As in your new code, you don't have to use `== true` in condition when you use boolean variables. See the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I strongly suspect the problem is that the `Text` property is never `null` for any of `txt_sel*`. Assuming these are text boxes in a UI, it's much more likely that if there's no text in the text box, the `Text` property will return `""` instead of `null`. That's the way most UI frameworks handle empty controls.

I would also suggest extracting the conditions into local variables first:

```
bool hasSel1 = txt_sel1.Text != "";
bool hasSel2 = txt_sel2.Text != "";
bool hasSel3 = txt_sel3.Text != "";
bool hasSel4 = txt_sel4.Text != "";
bool hasSel5 = txt_sel5.Text != "";

if (!hasSel1 && (!hasSel2 || !hasSel3 || !hasSel4 || !hasSel5)
{
    ...
}
```

And ideally, give your controls more meaningful names - a collection of variables with the same prefix but then a numeric suffix is very rarely a good idea, in terms of readability.

Answer (score 1):

I think for string better to use inbuild null and whitespace check function:

```
bool hasValue1 = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_sel1.Text);
bool hasValue2=  string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_sel2.Text);
bool hasValue3=  string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_sel3.Text);
bool hasValue4=  string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((txt_sel4.Text);
bool hasValue5 =  string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_sel5.Text);
```

And then define if condition on these bool. This case can handle unexpected null or white space values.

Comment: I updated my question with your suggested code but it is overwritting the value of txt_sel2. even it has value not going for next condition.

Answer (score 0):

That is bacause it probably doesn't find any of those conditions true.

If it would find a true condition it would execute that if block and won't event check the others.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what others have said, you should really have a final else statement in there to catch issues such as this:

```
else 
{
  throw new InvalidOperationException("My If Statement is Broken");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you all! My problem is solved by changing the conditions and your suggested alteration, following is the code may be helped some beginner like me.

```
 private void GetHash()
    {
        bool hasValue1 =  string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_sel1.Text);
        bool hasValue2 =  string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_sel2.Text);
        bool hasValue3 =  string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_sel3.Text);
        bool hasValue4 =  string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_sel4.Text);
        bool hasValue5 =  string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_sel5.Text);

        if (hasValue1 && (hasValue2 || hasValue3 || hasValue4 || hasValue5))
        {
            txt_sel1.Text = txt_selectedText.Text;
            return;
        }

        else if (hasValue2 && (!hasValue1 ||hasValue3 || hasValue4 || hasValue5 ))
        {                
                txt_sel2.Text = txt_selectedText.Text;
                return;
        }

        else if (hasValue3 && (!hasValue1 || !hasValue2 || hasValue4 || hasValue5 ))
        {               
                txt_sel3.Text = txt_selectedText.Text;
                return;                
        }

        else if (hasValue4 && (!hasValue1 || !hasValue2 || !hasValue3 || hasValue5 ))
        {
                txt_sel4.Text = txt_selectedText.Text;
                return;
        }

        else if (hasValue5 && (!hasValue1 || !hasValue2 || !hasValue3 || !hasValue4 ))
        {
            txt_sel5.Text = txt_selectedText.Text;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            CompareHash();
        }


    }
```

Comment: I was banging my head on the wall trying to figure out why it is not working in your case. What was the reason?

Comment: I think intial reason was checkin null value for Textbox.Text, as it will be null if it is explicitly set to null..

Comment: @Raging Bull reason was I was passing all the false conditions at first clause....Thanks for your Cooperation.

Comment: @Dreamweaver The question was why if else if not working properly so may be you can say that there was two problems to solve in order to make if else if works properly.